# Set reminder that repeated everyday?

Tags: ios

I want to set reminder between some time period that should be repeated everyday for that time period which should be set for reminder.Please help.

Comment: Look for local notifications in ios.

Comment: see this tutorial. http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: This question belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here at this tutorial, I think it might help you:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/